# Cannot write to hosts file with admin privileges in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, privileges, hosts

I've following line in app.manifest:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
```

And I'm writing to hosts file like this:

```
File.AppendAllText(Settings.hostsPath,
             Environment.NewLine
             + "127.0.0.1 " + url);
```

Then I run it through VS it works just fine. But when I run it from standalone exe file it won't let me write to hosts file. I've tried manually running file as administrator and it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: What exception is getting thrown?

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' is denied.

Comment: Have you tried turning off any anti-virus program that you might have running? The hosts file is a prime target that a lot of anti-virus programs have special protection for.

Comment: @itsme86 Yeah Kaspersky was blocking it. Maybe it would not be bad if it show some warning or something... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that Kaspersky Antivirus is blocking it without say a word.

After a bit more of Googling I've found it also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615128/how-to-give-permission-for-windows-form-net-program-for-editing-host-file

There is a screenshot where you can change it in Kaspersky (sorry it's in Czech in does not have option for english :/)

[image: Kaspersky modify Windows files]

In english it should be like: Application manager, find your program and select Properties, Files and system register - System files - Critical settings